# PSExec on Windows Server Startup Script

Tags: windows, powershell, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, psexec

I'm programatically launching a Google Cloud Compute Instance running Windows Server 2016 with a start up script.

The executable in the start up script requires to be launched as a specific user, so I'm trying to launch it with `psexec` to simulate said user:

`C:/psexec.exe \\\\WIN-SERVER-2016 -u WIN-SERVER-2016\\customuser -p custompassword -accepteula -w "c:/app" cmd /c  node index.js`

`c:/app/index.js` contains a simple hello world, which should write to a file.

If I log in as any user and launch this exact command from cmd, the file is written. Launching from the startup script (supplied as `windows-startup-script-cmd` in the Google Cloud Compute Engine Instance) results in no file written.

What could be the solution? Is there a more efficient way to execute a start-up script as a specific user?

Comment: Create a scheduled task to run at startup.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I already have a task running on startup. It doesn't properly execute psexec.

Comment: Then why would you even need `psexec`? Just configure the task to run as your custom user.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The command I'm running is dynamically generated and some software executed in the startup script requires data from a specific user profile.

Comment: So? Have the task run a script and update that script. Or a resource used by the script.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The task is launched from the Google instance using the `windows-startup-script-cmd` metadata key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the concern , I would not recommend you to use *PSEXEC* .

NOrmally, we use PSExec in order to invoke a GUI in the remote system which PS doesn't support by native.

In your case, I would suggest you to run using the **Invoke-Command**

**Something like this:**

```
$username = 'WIN-SERVER-2016\customuser'
$password = "custompassword"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

$Script_block = {cmd /c  node index.js}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName  WIN-SERVER-2016 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $Script_block
```

This should also take it from the Metadata key if you are using *windows-startup-script-cmd*

Note: I have not considered the *accepteula -w "c:/app"* part. Please incorporate the placeholders accordingly.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: I've never used Powershell before. Is this a Powershell script I'm supposed to load as the startup script for the instance? It does seem very useful, thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is a powershell one. you can run it in powershell ISE .. Go to Run > type Powershell_ise.. It will open up

Comment: @Dean: Accept the answer also if it helps you.

Comment: I will after testing properly today! :)

Comment: Sure. If there is any issue. Feel free to post it with the errors. We will do further analysis on that then